# Mybb forum automatically logs out a user

Tags: wordpress, mybb

I have integrated Mybb forum with wordpress 3.3.2 using zingiri. The URL is www.etrixdevenv.com/ssc2pg2/community. The etrixdevenv.com is our development server. And project name is ssc2pg.

The problem we are facing is that when one registered user (for trial) logs in, then it works just fine. But when any other user just visits (not log on) the community page (forum) then if the previous logged on user tries to post a new thread / reply or any other activity, it simply gets logged out. Can anybody suggest an answer? Also the formatting buttons are missing from the post editor.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cookie issue. Make sure that you're setting the cookie domain correctly in Settings of the Admin panel.